# Picker View Background Color during Rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, uipickerview

I am having an issue with my picker view rotating. I am using a normal UIPickerView and autorotation, all of which is done in code (but the autorotation isn't what I'm concerned about). The picker view does exactly what I want it to do after rotation. The issue is that my background is black, and during rotation the background of the picker view turns white in places. I am pretty sure that these are the deep subviews of the picker view simply because of debugging using Xcode's visual debugger and taking mid-rotation screen shots.

My question is, how do I get the background of the picker view to not appear momentarily white?

I have tried something along these lines:

```
-(void)setBackgroundBlackForSubviews:(NSArray *)subviews
{
    if (subviews.count) {
        for (UIView *view in subviews) {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [self setBackgroundBlackForSubviews:view.subviews];
        }
    }
}
```

and pass in `pickerView.subviews` as the initial parameter, but this doesn't produce the desired result.

So, what solution should I try to get the background to appear black throughout the entire rotation process?

Comment: I have same issue. Could you resolve it?